# Getting 500 - Internal Error Encountered with Youtube Broadcast Insert API

Tags: android, youtube-api, youtube-data-api, youtube-livestreaming-api

I am trying to insert a LiveBroadcast using Youtube LIVE streaming API.

Here is my **request** which I made on the API playground on [youtube API docs](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/live/docs/liveBroadcasts/insert).

```
POST https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/liveBroadcasts?part=snippet%2C%20id%2C%20status%2C%20contentDetails&key=[YOUR_API_KEY] HTTP/1.1

Authorization: Bearer [YOUR_ACCESS_TOKEN]
Accept: application/json
Content-Type: application/json

{
  "contentDetails": {
    "enableClosedCaptions": true,
    "enableEmbed": true,
    "enableLowLatency": true,
    "recordFromStart": true,
    "enableAutoStart": true,
    "enableAutoStop": true
  },
  "status": {
    "privacyStatus": "public",
    "selfDeclaredMadeForKids": true,
    "liveBroadcastPriority": "high",
    "madeForKids": true
  },
  "snippet": {
    "title": "My broadcasst",
    "description": "My Description",
    "scheduledStartTime": "2020-06-177T03:48:46.46Z",
    "scheduledEndTime": "2020-06-178T11:48:52.52Z"
  }
}
```

And the **response** that I am getting is

```
{
  "error": {
    "code": 500,
    "message": "Internal error encountered.",
    "errors": [
      {
        "message": "Internal error encountered.",
        "domain": "global",
        "reason": "backendError"
      }
    ],
    "status": "INTERNAL"
  }
}
```

Any help will be appreciated. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

The error was with the time format string that I had copied from google [docs](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/live/docs/liveBroadcasts?authuser=2) for ISO-8601 format, mentioned for all their time-relatedfields. I suggest creating your format string from [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html) for java code

Answer (score 0):

According to [the docs](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/live/docs/liveBroadcasts/insert#request-body), you're not supposed to provide the [`makeForKids`](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/live/docs/liveBroadcasts#status.madeForKids) property (that's the job of the API).

When calling for [`liveBroadcasts.insert`](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/live/docs/liveBroadcasts/insert) endpoint, if wanting to designate the respective broadcast as *child-directed*, you should use this property instead:

> [**status.selfDeclaredMadeForKids**](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/live/docs/liveBroadcasts#status.selfDeclaredMadeForKids) (*boolean*)
>
> In a liveBroadcasts.insert request, this property allows the channel owner to designate the broadcast as being child-directed. In a liveBroadcasts.list request, the property value is only returned if the channel owner authorized the API request.

The other properties that you shouldn't have set are `enableLowLatency` and `liveBroadcastPriority`.

Comment: I updated the payload and still getting 500
{
  "contentDetails": {
    "enableClosedCaptions": true,
    "enableEmbed": true,
    "recordFromStart": true,
    "enableAutoStart": true,
    "enableAutoStop": true
  },
  "status": {
    "privacyStatus": "public",
    "selfDeclaredMadeForKids": true
  },
  "snippet": {
    "title": "My broadcasst",
    "description": "My Description",
    "scheduledStartTime": "2020-06-177T03:48:46.46Z",
    "scheduledEndTime": "2020-06-178T11:48:52.52Z"
  }
}

Comment: Could you also fix the schedule datetime values, since they're invalid.